# I'm getting an error when I try to run PowerShell commands from a batch file

Tags: powershell, batch-file, command-prompt

I have an existing batch file. I need to show free space on C:. The best method I have found is to use PowerShell.

```
$disk = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DeviceID='C:'" | Select-Object FreeSpace
Write-Host ("{0}GB free" -f [math]::truncate($disk.FreeSpace / 1GB))
```

I can modify this by exiting with the result in errorlevel.

Powershell:

```
$disk = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DeviceID='C:'" | Select-Object Freespace
Exit ("{0}" -f [math]::truncate($disk.freespace / 1GB))
```

After exiting PS:

```
set FreeSpace=%errorlevel%
echo %FreeSpace%
```

And that works perfectly when I run it from command prompt. To make it work from a batch file, I need to escape a few characters.

```
Powershell $disk = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DeviceID=`'C:`'" ^| Select-Object Freespace ^
           Exit ("{0}" -f [math]::truncate($disk.freespace / 1GB))
set FreeSpace=%errorlevel%
echo %FreeSpace%
```

But I get the error:

```
Select-Object : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Exit'.
```

It's as if Select-Object is parsing the next line. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not familiar with batch files, I find them a pain to work with. You could create a string with all of your PowerShell commands and then execute that string with [Invoke-Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression?view=powershell-5.1). I would rather do this than having to deal with escaping stuff.

Comment: `EXIT` is another command.  When you want to run multiple commands on one line you need to separate the commands by a semi-colon.  As it stands the `SELECT-OBJECT` command thinks `EXIT` is a parameter for itself.

Comment: When you chose to use the escape character to put all of your Powershell code on multiple lines it thinks `EXIT` is part of the previous line. You can't have all your powershell code on multiple lines without using the escape character.  So you still need to follow the syntax of running multiple commands on one line by using the semicolon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- use `;` semicolon as Powershell command separator;
- use another kind of escaping quotes (double quotes are choked down);
- you can use an integer in Exit.

The code:

```
@echo OFF
Powershell -nopro $disk = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter """"DeviceID='D:'"""" ^| Select-Object Freespace; ^
           Write-Host (""""{0}GB free"""" -f [math]::round($disk.FreeSpace / 1GB)) -Fore Yellow; ^
           Exit ([math]::truncate($disk.freespace / 1GB))
set FreeSpace=%errorlevel%
echo %FreeSpace%
```

**Output**: `.\SO\67131203.bat`

> ```
> 796GB free
> 796
> ```

Comment: Ah. Your solution set the DeviceID to D: and changing it to C: works. Thanks!